# ArgoCD 2.5.x ha install results in redis pods initializing issue

Tags: redis, argocd

We are trying to install the ha argocd of verser 2.5.x(current stable version) on Kubernetes: v1.23.13
But the argocd-redis-ha-server-0 pod does not finalize the Initialization because the config-init container fails with

```
Start...

Initializing config..

Copying default redis config..

to '/data/conf/redis.conf'

Copying default sentinel config..

to '/data/conf/sentinel.conf'

Identifying redis master (get-master-addr-by-name)..

using sentinel (argocd-redis-ha), sentinel group name (argocd)

Could not connect to Redis at argocd-redis-ha:26379: Try again

Could not connect to Redis at argocd-redis-ha:26379: Try again

Could not connect to Redis at argocd-redis-ha:26379: Try again

Did not find redis master ()

Identify announce ip for this pod..

using (argocd-redis-ha-announce-0) or (argocd-redis-ha-server-0)

identified announce ()

/readonly-config/init.sh: line 239: Error: Could not resolve the announce ip for this pod.: not found
```

Installed ArgoCD resource - https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/blob/master/manifests/ha/install.yaml

Does anyone have any idea on how to resolve the above issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar error, ArgoCD is not starting correctly. Seems to me that it needs an additional pod for argo-cd-alpha-redis-ha-server statefulset. If I set the statefulset to 1 replica ArgoCD doesn't work and if I set to 2, I'm getting almost the same error:

```
Initializing config..
Copying default redis config.. to '/data/conf/redis.conf'
Copying default sentinel config.. to '/data/conf/sentinel.conf'
Identifying redis master (get-master-addr-by-name)..
using sentinel (argo-cd-alpha-redis-ha), sentinel group name (argocd)
Thu Jul  6 16:29:15 UTC 2023 Found redis master (172.20.198.165)
Identify announce ip for this pod..
using (argo-cd-alpha-redis-ha-announce-1) or (argo-cd-alpha-redis-ha-server-1)
identified announce ()
/readonly-config/init.sh: line 239: Error: Could not resolve the announce ip for this pod.: not found
```

I will continue searching...

Answer (score 0):

So there is an [issue on Github](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/11388) around this which provided some useful insights, where people have reported it was either because they were running k8s with the CoreDNS listening on 5353 and the NetworkPolicy resources for `argocd-redis-ha-server` and `argocd-redis-ha-proxy` having egress to only 53, or caused by other networking factors like IPv6 when the chart explicitly binds to IPv4 i.e 0.0.0.0.

Patch deleting out all the NetworkPolicy resources pulled from upstream worked in my case, since we needed to define via Calico anyway. If DNS port is the case, refer to the patch in the issue if preferring to retain the network policies:

```
  - patch: |-
      - op: replace
        path: /spec/egress/1/ports/0/port
        value: 5353
      - op: replace
        path: /spec/egress/1/ports/1/port
        value: 5353
    target:
      kind: NetworkPolicy
      name: argocd-redis-ha-proxy-network-policy
  - patch: |-
      - op: replace
        path: /spec/egress/1/ports/0/port
        value: 5353
      - op: replace
        path: /spec/egress/1/ports/1/port
        value: 5353
    target:
      kind: NetworkPolicy
      name: argocd-redis-ha-server-network-policy
```

otherwise I would recommend removing the redis-ha-server and redis-ha-proxy network policies and deleting the redis-ha-server and redis-ha-proxy pods to trigger a restart.

```
  - patch: |
      $patch: delete
      apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
      kind: NetworkPolicy
      metadata:
        name: argocd-redis-ha-proxy-network-policy
    target:
      kind: NetworkPolicy
      name: argocd-redis-ha-proxy-network-policy

  - patch: |
      $patch: delete
      apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
      kind: NetworkPolicy
      metadata:
        name: argocd-redis-ha-server-network-policy
    target:
      kind: NetworkPolicy
      name: argocd-redis-ha-server-network-policy
```

I would not recommend scaling down to 1, or modifying hardAntiAffinity to deploy all 3 onto one node (unless local development requires it) because it contradicts the need to use the HA chart. Be best off deploying the normal non-ha manifest

In addition we experienced another issue preventing writes to Redis, and this was caused by deploying onto a dev cluster with only one worker node whilst the `hardAntiAffinity=True` is [configured by default in the redis-ha chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/redis-ha#configuration).

It manifested as log and UI messages complaining about:

```
time="2023-07-28T02:06:23Z" level=error msg="finished unary call with code Unknown" error="error getting cached app resource tree: cache: key is missing" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.method=ResourceTree grpc.service=application.ApplicationService grpc.start_time="2023-07-28T02:06:21Z" grpc.time_ms=1819.046 span.kind=server system=grpc
```

and

```
time="2023-07-27T07:30:03Z" level=warning msg="getConnectionState cache set error https://git-example.com/gitorg/gitrepo: NOREPLICAS Not enough good replicas to write."
```

The fix can either be deploying with this as False or editing/patching the `argocd-redis-ha-cm` in order to change `min-replicas-to-write 0`. I'm mentioning this because I suspect this is also why in my case the pods won't initialise, since we are not running DNS on port 5353.